# How to get EXIF orientation from img tag

Tags: reactjs, image, orientation, exif-js

I am trying to get EXIF data from img tag but it is undefined.

This is my code

```
const newimg = document.getElementById('campic');
getExif(newimg) {
  if(newimg){
    EXIF.getData(newimg, function() {
            var orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
      console.log("orientation",orientation);
            if(orientation == 6) {
                newimg.className = "camview rotate90";
            } else if(orientation == 8) {
                newimg.className = "camview rotate270";
            } else if(orientation == 3) {
                newimg.className = "camview rotate180";
            }
        });
  }
};
```

```
<Img src={this.state.new_item.image_placeholder} id="campic" class="camview"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the image's EXIF data from http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi

Then you can make a React component like:

```js
import React from "react";
import EXIF from "exif-js";

function ImageMeta() {
  function handleChange({
    target: {
      files: [file]
    }
  }) {
    if (file && file.name) {
      EXIF.getData(file, function() {
        var exifData = EXIF.pretty(this);
        if (exifData) {
          console.log(exifData);
          console.log(EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation"));
        } else {
          console.log("No EXIF data found in image '" + file.name + "'.");
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      id="file"
      accept=".jpg, .png, .heif, .heic"
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}

export default ImageMeta;
```

Here's the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gwfe3y?file=ImageMega.js) if you want to see it in action.